# Lactase enzyme products and dental health

Tags: tooth-decay, lactose-intolerant, lactase

It is possible to buy lactase enzyme products, such as chewable tablets or drops, that convert lactose in dairy produts to glucose and galactose on-the-fly (supplementing or replacing low human lactase production).

Some of these, particularly chewable tablets, may interact with lactose while the lactose-containing food is still in the mouth.

What is the effect on dental health of glucose/galactose compared to lactose? Is there a higher risk of dental health problems, e.g. cavities?

If glucose and/or galactose are more detrimental to dental health than lactose, would swallowing the chewable tablet supplement (often also a listed administration method) be better for dental health?